# Capturing a process running more than 30 mins and send the report

Tags: python

I have written a small code which is capturing the "rm" process running on the OS.. Below is the code

```
bash-4.1$ cat CheckRM1.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

def Check_Ps():
    ps = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-eo' 'pid,user,args,etime='], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = ps.communicate()[0]
    for line in output.splitlines():
        if 'rm' in line:
            pss = (line)
            print pss

Check_Ps()
```

> When i run the code, it generate the output in the below form:
>   this basically giving the process ID number(PID) , user name, command & at last the total time since the process running.
>   This time basically uses the format `[[dd-]hh:]mm:ss`. In my case its running more than 9 mins.

```
bash-4.1$ ./CheckRM1.py
22908 karn     rm -i e ee q r w                  09:19
```

Now i'm looking to search the process which are running more 30 mins and Just print them out and send a mail. So, any idea how to capture only process running more than 30 mins, will be appreciated.

NOte: I'm using python 2.7 .

Comment: You want to monitor the process created by the OS or by you?

Comment: @bigbounty, I want to run this code on multiple system and want to capture "rm" process by running any user and then want to see  the time  if more than 30 mins then store that into a variable so, that can be send out as an alert.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.Read the question properly and then answer

Comment: @bigbounty, my bad , I'm somewhat unable to understand you. I want to monitor the process created by me not Os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: ... how to capture only process running more than 30 mins

You are already close, `split(..` the time from line by blanks, e.g.

```
import re

time_str = line.split(' ')[-1]
#  format [[dd-]hh:]mm:ss
time_items = [int(e) for e in re.split('[-:]', time_str)]

dd = 0
if len(time_items) == 2:
    hh = 0
    mm,ss = time_items
elif len(time_items) == 3:
    hh, mm, ss = time_items
else:
    dd,hh,mm,ss = time_items

print('Process is running {} Days {} Hours {} Minutes {} Seconds'.format(dd,hh,mm,ss))

time_minutes = (hh*60) + mm 
if  time_minutes >= 30:
    # do report
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***

Comment: @stofl , thnx let me check.

Comment: your code its running i just change `int` into `str` because it was throwing error for int like `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '51-18'` , moreover i want the process names to be  printed which are running more than 30 mins as well.

Comment: i forgot to put that data, now i have edited the main post with the output data and the command and variable which is producing this.

Comment: @stofl , thnx let me check again.

Comment: @stofl,   its giving an error  `time_hours = int(time_items[-3])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '52-02'`

Comment: @stolf,  can you explain the code So, i can use this into if elif condition for mins, hoours, and days.. mean to say, if any process has the number in day feild then only say `"process is running more that "number" days"`
if hours then similarly `"process is running more that "number" of hours"`

Comment: thanks , got it now.. excellent one. Though already upvoted the answer the reason for accepting which i couldn't did because i dont see answer check mark on your answer to accept it.

Comment: See this help page, should be on the left: http://stackoverflow.com/tour